# Read XML Attribute using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

How can I read an XML attribute using C#'s XmlDocument?

I have an XML file which looks somewhat like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MyConfiguration xmlns="http://tempuri.org/myOwnSchema.xsd" SuperNumber="1" SuperString="whipcream">
    <Other stuff />
</MyConfiguration>
```

How would I read the XML attributes SuperNumber and SuperString?

Currently I'm using XmlDocument, and I get the values in between using XmlDocument's `GetElementsByTagName()` and that works really well. I just can't figure out how to get the attributes?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

```
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName(...);
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{
    string attrVal = elemList[i].Attributes["SuperString"].Value;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. it really works and it doesn't need any paths and nothing. simply superb!!

Answer (score 91):

You should look into [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).  Once you start using it, you'll find its a lot more efficient and easier to code than iterating through lists.  It also lets you directly get the things you want.

Then the code would be something similar to

```
string attrVal = doc.SelectSingleNode("/MyConfiguration/@SuperNumber").Value;
```

Note that XPath 3.0 became a W3C Recommendation on April 8, 2014.

Answer (score 8):

You can migrate to XDocument instead of XmlDocument and then use Linq if you prefer that syntax. Something like:

```
var q = (from myConfig in xDoc.Elements("MyConfiguration")
         select myConfig.Attribute("SuperString").Value)
         .First();
```

Answer (score 8):

I have an Xml File books.xml

```
<ParameterDBConfig>
    <ID Definition="1" />
</ParameterDBConfig>
```

Program:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("D:/siva/books.xml");
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ID");     
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)     
{
    string attrVal = elemList[i].Attributes["Definition"].Value;
}
```

Now, `attrVal` has the value of `ID`.

Answer (score 5):

`XmlDocument.Attributes` perhaps? (Which has a method GetNamedItem that will presumably do what you want, although I've always just iterated the attribute collection)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your example document is in the string variable `doc`

```
> XDocument.Parse(doc).Root.Attribute("SuperNumber")
1
```

Answer (score 1):

If your XML contains namespaces, then you can do the following in order to obtain the value of an attribute:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

// content is your XML as string
xmlDoc.LoadXml(content);

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());

// make sure the namespace identifier, URN in this case, matches what you have in your XML 
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");

// get the value of Destination attribute from within the Response node with a prefix who's identifier is "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" using XPath
var str = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:Response/@Destination", nsmgr);
if (str != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str.Value);
}
```

More on XML namespaces [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) and [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/xml-namespaces-explained/).