# C# obtaining XML attributes

Tags: c#, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Read XML Attribute using XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933687/c-read-xml-attribute-using-xmldocument)

In C# if I were to have the XMLDocument containing:

```
<Hello>
<Person:"Alan" Saying:"My name is Alan">
</Hello>
```

Then how might I obtain the single attribute "Saying"? I've found code which works when a single attribute is contained within the "<>" however it does not appear to work where there are multiple attributes inside as is above.

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm rather a C# novice :)

Comment: This is not a well-formed Xml document.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid XML to me.

Comment: Check out the XmlSerializer. Also, those colons should be equals signs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933687/c-read-xml-attribute-using-xmldocument

Comment: @SteveKonves: Even then, it wouldn't be well-formed Xml. `Person` in the sample serves as both an element name and an attribute name for some reason.

Comment: true. that second element needs an element name and a closing tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, that is not valid xml.  I think you want something like

```
<Hello>
    <Person name="Alan" Saying="My name is Alan" />
</Hello>
```

and the simplest way to get Alan's Saying is

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("filename.xml");
string saying = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Person[@name=Alan]").Attributes["saying"].Value;
```

for  a more detailed explanation of why that works, see  [XPath Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your XML should be:

```
<Hello>
    <Person name="Alan" saying="My name is Alan"/>
</Hello>
```

Your class to deserialize this would be:

```
public class Hello
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Saying { get; set; }
}
```

How to use it:

```
// Create a new XmlSerializer instance with the type of the test class
XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Hello));

// load xml into string reader
StringReader reader = new StringReader(yourXmlString);

// Load the object saved above by using the Deserialize function
Hello LoadedObj = (Hello)SerializerObj.Deserialize(reader);
```

Check out the MSDN article for more info on how to use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)