# xml multiple attributes vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

Hello all i have an xml like this

```
<root>
<page key"page1.aspx" value="page1" />
<page key"page2.aspx" value="cookepage" >
</root>
```

now what i want to get is i want key and value attributes at the same time as i want them to add into a NameValueCollection

like this

NVC.Add(key,value)

untill now i have done this

```
 For Each Item as XmlNode In xdoc.SelectNodes("//*/@*")
' But this returns me only key or value attribute at a time and i can not add it to NVC
 Next
```

looking for a good suggestion

Comment: select the `page` nodes. then for each node, loop over attributes. `if attrib.Name='key' then ... elseif attrib.Name='value' then ... end if`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/933698/1043824

Comment: then please mark as answer and close the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select the `page` nodes.

then for each node, loop over attributes.

`if attrib.Name='key' then ... elseif attrib.Name='value' then ... end if`.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/933698/1043824