# How to get/read data from the xml file in C# Windows application

Tags: c#

I have my xml file in following format---

```
<Tag_1 Interpolation="true" DefaultSpacing="100">
    <Items>
      <ValueItem Position="0" Value="40" />
      <ValueItem Position="11000" Value="30" />
    </Items>
 </Tag_1>

  <Tag_2 Interpolation="true" DefaultSpacing="100">
    <Items>
      <ValueItem Position="0" Value="40" />
      <ValueItem Position="11000" Value="30" />
    </Items>
  </Tag_2>

  <Tag_3 Interpolation="true" DefaultSpacing="100">
    <Items>
        <ValueItem Position="0" Value="50" />
        <ValueItem Position="37500" Value="50" />
        <ValueItem Position="39900" Value="50" />
        <ValueItem Position="40000" Value="46" />
        <ValueItem Position="43000" Value="43" />
        <ValueItem Position="43100" Value="50" />
    </Items>
  </Tag_3>

  <Tag_4 Interpolation="true" DefaultSpacing="100">
    <Items>
        <ValueItem Position="2000" Value="6" />
        <ValueItem Position="45000" Value="6" />
    </Items>
  </Tag_4>
```

and I wants to read/get the data from **position** and **value** and wants to store that data into the respective ArrayList but don't know how to do it. Please help

Comment: Google `C# xml read attribute`

Comment: ...and show your efforts.

Comment: Or see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933687/read-xml-attribute-using-xmldocument ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dnyanesh.

To read XML-files you can use System.Xml inluded to .NET Framework.

It works a kind of this:

```
using System.Xml;

...

XmlDocument MyXmlFile = new XmlDocument();
MyXmlFile.LoadXml(PATH_TO_MY_XML);

// Using 
XmlNode xmlValueItem = MyXmlFile.GetElementsByTagName("ValueItem")[0];

string position = xmlValueItem.Attributes["Position"].InnerText;
```

Google for System.Xml and XPath to work with XML documents.

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Record7.xml"));
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();

    Record.DataSource = ds;
    Record.DataBind();
}
```