# How would I retrieve Query Parameter and name Values From XML String

Tags: c#, xml, regex, parsing

How would i parse the following, it wont change at least the layout of the line. So I need to be able to get the Query Parmeter value out   ie TypeProjectionId and also the value of Name=? does anybody have any ideas at all?

I am using this to get the text from an xml file.

```
                string path = "/View/Data/ItemsSource";
                XmlNodeList nodeList = currentDocument.SelectNodes(path);
                IDictionary<string, string> keyValuePairList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                string itemsource;
                itemsource = "";
                foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
                {

                    itemsource = node.InnerXml;
                     //   keyValuePairList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(node.Attributes[0].Value, node.Attributes[0].Value));

                }
```

Result of itemsource

```
    <AdvancedListSupportClass xmlns=\"clr-namespace:Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ViewFramework;assembly=Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ViewFramework\" xmlns:av=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" xmlns:s=\"clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib\" DataTypeName=\"\" AdapterName=\"viewframework://Adapters/AdvancedList\" FullUpdateAdapter=\"dataportal:EnterpriseManagementObjectProjectionAdapter\" DataSource=\"mom:ManagementGroup\" IsRecurring=\"True\" RecurrenceFrequency=\"{x:Static s:Int32.MaxValue}\" FullUpdateFrequency=\"1\" Streaming=\"true\">
      <AdvancedListSupportClass.Parameters>
        <QueryParameter Parameter=\"TypeProjectionId\" Value=\"$MPElement[Name='System.WorkItem.Incident.View.ProjectionType']$\" />
      </AdvancedListSupportClass.Parameters>
    </AdvancedListSupportClass>
```

Comment: punctuation in your question would help

Comment: A decent question title would also help

Comment: So you want to get the attributevalues of a node? Try this! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933687/read-xml-attribute-using-xmldocument

Comment: Yes that is correct and @DavidS. sorry about the punchation I have dislexia in spelling

Answer (score 0):

Your XML has default namespace so you need to use `XmlNamespaceManager` to be able to query the XML using XPath. For example, to get value of `Parameter` attribute you can do as follow :

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());

//register ns prefix to point to default namespace 
nsManager.AddNamespace("ns", node.FirstChild.GetNamespaceOfPrefix(""));

//use the namespace manager and registered prefix to get desired element
string xpath = "/ns:AdvancedListSupportClass/ns:AdvancedListSupportClass.Parameters/ns:QueryParameter";
var queryParameters = node.SelectNodes(xpath, nsManager);

foreach(XmlNode queryParameter in queryParameters)
{
    //get value of Parameter attribute of each <QueryParameter>
    Console.WriteLine(queryParameter.Attributes["Parameter"].Value);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but having trouble implmenting it is their no way i can just parse it its values out as i getting that all as one string just their could be multple paremters though

Comment: Updated the code to accommodate case where there are multiple `<QueryParameter>`s

Comment: i think this is over complicating it I already have this in strong typed class "<QueryParameter Parameter=\"TypeProjectionId\" Value=\"$MPElement[Name='System.WorkItem.Incident.View.ProjectionType']$\" xmlns=\"clr-namespace:Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ViewFramework;assembly=Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ViewFramework\" />"

all i need to do is extract the typeprotectionid and value of name: can i not just parse this line?