# Xml serialize get attribute on list node

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I currently have a structure as such

```cs
[XmlRoot("command")]
public class Command
{
    [XmlArray("itemlist")]
    [XmlArrayItem("item")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("itemid")]
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
}
```

which works great for it's purpose, but given this xml

```xml
<command>
    <itemlist totalsize="999">
        <item itemid="1">
        <item itemid="2">
        ...
    </itemlist>
</command>
```

how do I get `totalsize` from `itemlist` when deserializing? 
The XML is something I receive and is not something i can control.
I'm not looking for `GetAttributeValue` or similar, but purely using xmlserializer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read XML Attribute using XmlDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933687/read-xml-attribute-using-xmldocument)

Comment: YOu need to add an attribute to the4 Command class similar to the ItemID attribute in the Item class.

Comment: Hint: copy your xml, go to visual studio and select *Edit > Paste Special > Paste XML as classes*. Though names mapping you should don manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split `itemlist` and `item` into two classes.

```
[XmlRoot("command")]
public class Command
{
    [XmlElement("itemlist")]
    public ItemList ItemList { get; set; }
}

public class ItemList
{
    [XmlAttribute("totalsize")]
    public int TotalSize { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("itemid")]
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
}
```

As an aside, note that an `XmlRoot` attribute is only relevant on the *root* element. The one you have on `Item` is ignored in this instance.

Comment: I figured as much, but hoped that I didn't need to make another class just to hold the extra totalsize.