# how to get value from xml attribute using c#

Tags: c#, xml

Here is my XML code:

```
<Car>
      <PTY name="XYZ" value="0"></PTY>
</Car>
```

I want to get the value of attribute value from this XML by using conditions like

```
if(<Car> == true){
//retrive attribute value
}
```

PS: i am new to xml!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read XML Attribute using XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933687/read-xml-attribute-using-xmldocument)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) for deserialize you string to Car class and simply check property value