# need to get a number from an xml file using Regex

Tags: c#

I have a scenario where I have an xml content and I need to get the version number from that file. For example below is the text.

```
<testing Version1 = "1.1" Version2 = "1.3">
<name> Example </Name>
<Description>sample description</Description>
</testing>
```

I need the Version2 value i.e., 1.3. Is it possible to get it by using Regex?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Why not use `XDocument`?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933687/read-xml-attribute-using-xmldocument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without a regular expression - example:

```
var xml = @"<testing Version1 = ""1.1"" Version2 = ""1.3"">
<Name> Example </Name>
<Description>sample description</Description>
</testing>";

string version2 = XElement.Parse(xml).Attribute("Version2").Value;
```